# Positioning and Aligning Nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, business-cards

I am trying to make a business card and have made the following so far (based on [this](https://github.com/opieters/business-card)):

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,final]{article}

% set all margins to 0 and set business card size
\usepackage[paperwidth=3.5in,paperheight=2in,margin=0cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}

\usepackage{parskip}         % remove paragraph indents
\usepackage{fontspec}        % load external fonts
\usepackage{tikz}            % drawing
\usepackage{fontawesome}     % icon font
\usepackage{xcolor}          % more colour options

% load and configure tikz libraries
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}

% load external font
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}

% define some lengths for internal spacing
\newlength{\seplinewidth}    \setlength{\seplinewidth}{2cm}
\newlength{\seplineheight}   \setlength{\seplineheight}{1pt}
\newlength{\seplinedistance} \setlength{\seplinedistance}{0.3cm}

% colour options
\definecolor{seplinecolour}{HTML}{357f2d}  % green
\definecolor{iconcolour}{HTML}{2f3142}     % dark
\definecolor{textcolour}{HTML}{2f3142}     % dark
\definecolor{jobtitlecolour}{HTML}{474a65} % light dark

% change global colour
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{textcolour}}

% \usepackage[colorgrid=true,gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  % \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node (logo) {\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{isulogotest.pdf}}; %\\
          \node [below= of logo.south west, anchor=north west] (name)  {My First and Last Name};
      \node[below=\seplinedistance of logo] (hl1) {};
      \matrix  [ below = of logo.south east, anchor=north east,%
               column 1/.style={anchor=west,color=iconcolour},%
               column 2/.style={anchor=west}] (contact){
            \node{\faEnvelope}; & \node[font=\normalsize]{myname@iastate.edu}; \\
            \node{\faPhone};    & \node{+1 202 202 2022};  \\
            \node{\faLinkedin}; & \node{/in/myname};    \\
      };

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

You can clearly see that there is excessive white space under the logo, and the right and left material are not aligned (the first and last name are higher than the email --- you can turn on the grid if you want to see it).

How do I fix it? I tried fiddling with `anchor` but to no avail (maybe because of `matrix` or my `ignorance` or both?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't provide the logo PDF file, I use this one as example for the logo:
[image]
However, it should be working whatever the size of the PDF figure. I draw the box for each part of your contents. In this way, it's better for you to see how they are aligned each other. I comment a empty node in between which I don't know why you put it there. The reason why they are not aligned is because you using node for the left side but node in a matrix for the right side. They have different inner separate distance. So you can put the left side content in a matirx with node as well in order to align them. The white space under the logo can be adjusted by giving a dimension in `below` command (e.g. `below= 0.5cm  of logo.south west`). Also, I add `\null\vfill` before the tikz and `\vfill` after the tikz to put the contents in the center of the page vertically.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,final]{article}

% set all margins to 0 and set business card size
\usepackage[paperwidth=3.5in,paperheight=2in,margin=0cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}

\usepackage{parskip}         % remove paragraph indents
\usepackage{fontspec}        % load external fonts
\usepackage{tikz}            % drawing
\usepackage{fontawesome}     % icon font
\usepackage{xcolor}          % more colour options

% load and configure tikz libraries
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}

% load external font
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}

% define some lengths for internal spacing
\newlength{\seplinewidth}    \setlength{\seplinewidth}{2cm}
\newlength{\seplineheight}   \setlength{\seplineheight}{1pt}
\newlength{\seplinedistance} \setlength{\seplinedistance}{0.3cm}

% colour options
\definecolor{seplinecolour}{HTML}{357f2d}  % green
\definecolor{iconcolour}{HTML}{2f3142}     % dark
\definecolor{textcolour}{HTML}{2f3142}     % dark
\definecolor{jobtitlecolour}{HTML}{474a65} % light dark

% change global colour
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{textcolour}}

% \usepackage[colorgrid=true,gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (logo) [draw] {\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{isulogotest.pdf}}; %\\
\matrix [draw,below= 0.5cm  of logo.south west, anchor=north west] (name)  {\node {My First and Last Name};\\};
%\node[below=\seplinedistance of logo] (hl1) {}; % I comment this empty node which I don't know why you put it here
\matrix [draw, below = 0.5cm of logo.south east, anchor=north east,%
column 1/.style={anchor=west,color=iconcolour},%
column 2/.style={anchor=west}] (contact)
{
\node{\faEnvelope}; & \node[font=\normalsize]{myname@iastate.edu}; \\
\node{\faPhone};    & \node{+1 202 202 2022}; \\
\node{\faLinkedin}; & \node{/in/myname}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]